# What is the default table storage format for Swisscom MariaDb Ent?

Tags: mariadb, swisscomdev

When creating a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `dummy` (
  `userid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `providerid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `provideruserid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and defining a PK like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE dummy ADD PRIMARY KEY (userid,providerid,provideruserid);
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

I think the following are set correctly and therefore most probably not the problem:

```
innodb_file_format=Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table=ON
innodb_large_prefix=ON
```

Most likely the table storage format is causing issues here, but I'm not able to check the defined default.
As per the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-storage-formats/), the default table storage format for MariaDB (since 10.2.2) is `DYNAMIC` - if it is `DYNAMIC` then this would be perfect, but this seems not to be the case.

Does anyone know the default table storage format in Swisscom MariaDB Ent. and why it is not `DYNAMIC`? (Probably :))

Comment: Often the `255` is overkill.  `191` will fit.  Also 10.2 increases the 767 limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our version of MariaDB in Prd:

```
select VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.22-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Quote from MariaDB KB [XtraDB/InnoDB Storage Formats](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-storage-formats/)

> `Compact`
>
> `Compact` was the default format until MariaDB 10.2.1, and is suitable
>   for general use if the Antelope file format is used. It was introduced
>   in MySQL 5.0.
>
> In the `Compact` storage format (as in Redundant) `BLOB` and `TEXT` columns
>   are partly stored in the row page. At least 767 bytes are stored in
>   the row; values which exceed this value are are stored in dedicated
>   pages. Since `Compact` and Redundant rows maximum size is about 8000
>   bytes, this limits the number of `BLOB` or `TEXT` columns that can be used
>   in a table. Each `BLOB` page is 16KB, regardless the size of the data.
>
> Other columns can be stored in different pages too, if they exceed the
>   row page's size limit.

Our version of MariaDB in Lab (soon to be deployed on Prd). This the [relevant line in bosh release](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-mysql-release/blob/v36.9.0/packages/mariadb/packaging#L4).

```
select VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.26-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How to fix the error `ERROR 1709 (HY000): Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.` on Swisscom Application Cloud (have a look at the diff `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC`):

```
MariaDB [stackoverflow]> CREATE TABLE `dummy` (
    ->   `userid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    ->   `providerid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    ->   `provideruserid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [stackoverflow]> ALTER TABLE dummy ADD PRIMARY KEY (userid,providerid,provideruserid);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [stackoverflow]> show index from dummy;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| dummy |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | userid         | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dummy |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | providerid     | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dummy |          0 | PRIMARY  |            3 | provideruserid | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here the code for copy and paste:

```
CREATE TABLE `dummy` 
             ( 
                          `userid`         VARCHAR(255) collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
                          `providerid`     VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
                          `provideruserid` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL 
             ) 
             engine=innodb row_format=dynamic DEFAULT charset=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: @fyobor-glebov many thanks for the detailed explanation just a comment to your answer: 'is suitable for general use if the Antelope file format is used'...this is not the case, the the default fileformat is 'Barracuda'